# AJAX Process Returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to process an AJAX request but the result of the process is an undefined value.

The returned value from converted data is undefined, and so when I return the overall value from the done function it is also undefined.

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
var download = $.ajax({url: url});
    download.done(function(downloaded_data) {
        if(typeof downloaded_data !== 'undefined'){ 
            console.log(1);
            var converted_data = csv2geojson.csv2geojson(downloaded_data, function (err, data) {
                // console.log(data);
                return converted_data;
            });
            console.log('Converted Data to GEOJSON');
            console.log(converted_data);
        };
        // return converted_data;
    });
```

Comment: tried calling succes in ajax?

Comment: @MrKhan OP does: `download.done(`

Comment: What does your service return?

Comment: 1
data.js:11 Converted Data to GEOJSON
data.js:12 undefined